# Liferay service builder get last modified

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

Somebody know how to get the last row modified from a table?
For example:

I have a Service Builder with a "Car" entity, this entity has a column called "LastModified". I want something that get the one "Car" (the last cart modified).

I don't know if create a finder with where clause is a good practice.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First off, service builder entities have a column called "modifiedDate" by default. Just want to make sure you're aware of that so you aren't creating redundant columns: "LastModified" and "modifiedDate".

Secondly, you could use either a custom SQL query or a dynamic query to get the Car with the most recent modifiedDate. Both approaches are documented:

- https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-custom-sql-queries
- https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/leveraging-hibernates-criteria-api

Personally, I'd try the dynamic query approach (leveraging hibernate's criteria API) first. I think it's slightly simpler.

In your finder method, you could do something like this:

```
    Order order = OrderFactoryUtil.desc("modifiedDate");

    DynamicQuery carQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Car.class).addOrder(order).setLimit(0, 1);

    List<Car> cars = CarLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(carQuery);
```

The setLimit(0, 1) limits the result of the query to only the first Car.

Comment: Also, you can use `LIMIT 1`, if want to get only single record.

Comment: Updated answer to include invoking setLimit(0, 1) on the query.